# How we get all media data as like (Video, Image , Audio) only By Device Sdcard In an android

Tags: android

Media data Means all Video, Audio, Image. Get all Folders media Data And show a Grid view. You can see the Gallery for Reference. I want show all media data as like gallery in Grid view in an android.

Comment: The media scanner has that information for you.

Comment: Stephan Branczyk  can you send me some references or sample code.